# Use DocuSign to generate PDF and replace the form element values inside

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have defined a housing purchase contract template, which contains the form elements of house address, postcode and other information. I want to use the API of Docusign to fill in the contents of these forms, for example, I provide a Dictionary data source to its API, and then its API can automatically replace my form content based on the field data I provide. And return the replacement PDF file to me.

Additional functions:

I think on this template, you can also draw a picture in the position, or draw a bar code in the position.

But when I looked at Docusign, I didn't see this type of Api. Can someone help me?Thanks

Comment: That is a great question but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: Not really sure what is your question. Anchor Tags is what I am thinking about. Check this link: https://support.docusign.com/answers/00001063